# How can I solve my meditation problem?

Tags: logical-deduction

I have been given a guide on how to reach satisfaction, and part of this guide requires me to meditate exactly for 90 minutes.

I have only been provided 2 oil-soaked ropes which last for 2 hours each when lit, and matches. (To time myself with)

I don't have a knife on me, and I am too weak to break it with my hands.

How can I meditate for exactly 90 minutes?

(Note: If you have seen a similar variation of this please don't answer)

Comment: I _have_ seen a similar (indeed more general) version of this, and it was [on this site](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/170/burning-ropes-as-timers-how-many-time-intervals-can-be-measured). VTC as duplicate (but also +1 since it's a good puzzle).

Comment: I will come downvote any answer that requires you to 'lite the second rope' thus breaking the meditate :D

Comment: Wait, your guide says 90 minutes, but you want to meditate for 45?

Comment: @randal'thor I should post this comment on Kendal Frey's question or diabonas' answer, but both appear to not be active on this site (last post in 2014); I hope discussing that answer here is ok but if not, I'll post this as a new question. The answer by diabonas is interesting, but only refers directly to the $\frac{m}{2^n}$ form in the sum near the bottom, and then only (it seems) relies on a common $2^n$ denominator for $t_{r,l}$. If we changed the form from the start to have a $3^n$ denominator, say, or indeed any other denominator, the argument still seems to hold. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry I meant 90 minutes, I just forgot to change the 45 because I was changing the question so someone else couldn't google it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To time 90 minutes as your guide suggests:

Lay the ropes next to each other.

> Light one rope from both ends.

When it burns out (1 hour)

> light the other rope at the middle (this is why you lay them next to each other) and at both its ends.

This second rope will burn for

> 30 minutes

, giving you a total of 90 minutes.

Comment: question asks for 45, but guide says 90 I think that was a typo.